# Python, moving object with arrow keys

Tags: python

I need to create an object (specifically oval) using Python that moves on its own or enables the user to move the object with arrow keys. I need to do so using these two `def`.

```py
import tkinter 
def motion():
    if m==1:
        can.move (id, 0,-5)
    elif m==3:
        can.move (id,0, 5)
    elif m==0:
        can.move (id,5, 0)
    else:
        can.move (id, - 5,0)
    can.after (50, motion)
def arrows (event):
    global m
    if event.keysym=='Up':
        m==1
    elif event.keysym=='Down':
        m==3
    elif event.keysym=='Right':
        m==0
    else:
        m==2
can=tkinter.Canvas (width=800,height=800)
can.pack ()
id=can.create_oval (100,100,150,150) 
can.bind ('<Button-1>',motion)
can.bind_all ('<Key>', arrows)
```

Comment: do you have to use exactly these definitions? Could be done a lot easier.

Comment: Can you explain what is the issue you are encountering with your script? You have mentioned what you want to achieve but have not explain the issue(s) you are encountering with your script.

Comment: Your question doesn't include a question. You've just made a statement. Please [edit] the question and actually ask something.

Comment: Never mind, i have finally managed to see my mistake, but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so here is what I needed.

```
import tkinter 
def motion():
      if m==1:
           can.move (id, 0,-5)
      elif m==3:
           can.move (id,0, 5)
      elif m==0:
           can.move (id,5, 0)
      else:
           can.move (id, - 5,0)
      can.after (50, motion)
def arrows (event):
    global m
    if event.keysym=='Up':
          m=1
    elif event.keysym=='Down':
          m=3
    elif event.keysym=='Right':
          m=0
    else:
          m=2
can=tkinter.Canvas (width=800,height=800)
can.pack ()
id=can.create_oval (100,100,150,150) 
m=3
motion () 
can bind ('<Button-1>',motion)
can.bind_all ('<Key>', arrows)
```